# Error message from RxAndroidBle

Tags: android, android-service, bluetooth-lowenergy, rx-android, rxandroidble

I have an Android Service that is giving me the following error message when it is being destroyed:

Service io.aeroscope.aeroscope.AeroscopeBluetoothService has leaked IntentReceiver com.polidea.rxandroidble.RxBleAdapterStateObservable$1$1@3d91b742 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
                                                                          at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.(LoadedApk.java:944)

The only subscription in the service is unsubscribed in the `onDestroy()` method (shown in its entirety):

```
if( !scanSubscription.isUnsubscribed() ) scanSubscription.unsubscribe(); 
super.onDestroy();
```

Where is this message coming from and how do I fix it? (Also, is the test for `.isUnsubscribed()` needed? Should `super.onDestroy()` come first?)

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: Sadly, no. But this project has ended and I'm not inclined to spend any more time on it.

Comment: I find a solution, the unsubscribe call seem to be asynchrone, so we have to wait before calling super.onDestroy() or add a sleep just before

Comment: Good to know! I guess you could just spinlock on isUnsubscribed()